# Find FEW most frequent element in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have already created a method that finds ONE most frequent number in array and how many times it is repeated. However, my task is to find few numbers if they are repeated the same amount of times. Should I create another method or how can I find a solution?

```
 public static void most(Ring[] rings, int numCounter, out int popHallmark, out int amount)
    {
        amount = 1;
        popHallmark = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numCounter; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int temp = rings[i].HallMark;
            count++;
            for (int k = 0; k < numCounter; k++)
            {
                if (i != k)
                {
                    if (k > i)
                    {
                        if (temp == rings[k].HallMark)
                        {
                            count++;
                            if (count > amount)
                            {
                                popHallmark = temp; // most popular hallmark
                                amount = count; //amount of rings that has this hallmark
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: To get grouped data ordered by frequency, it is enough to do ```rings.Take(numCounter).GroupBy(x=>x.HallMark).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count())```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `GroupBy()` linq method.
suppose you have an array of int, than you can do something like this:

```
var groupedNumbers = yourArray.GroupBy(x=>x)
```

This means that every group will contain numbers that are the same.
Next you need to call `Count()` method on every group to get how many elements does a group contain.

```
var numberCount = groupedNumberes.Select(x=>new{
    number = x.Key,
    numberOfOccurrences = x.Count
})
```

The numberCount will contain a collection of annonymous objects containing the number and how many times it were repeated.
Hope this helps you.

**Edit:** 
You than can order the `numberCount` and get the "FEW" numbers you need:

```
numberCount.OrderByDescending(x=>x.numberOfOccurrences).Take(howManyNumbersYouNeed).Select(x=>x.number)
```